# Seeking list of ArcMap capabilities not available in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, limitations

Is there anywhere I can find a listing of features in ArcMap that are not yet available in ArcGIS Pro?

It would save a lot of frustration & wasted time searching for things that haven't yet been added to Pro.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of features that are not available?

Comment: Geometric Networks is the only one I can think of as of Pro 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

The ArcGIS Pro Help has a page titled [Tools that are not available in ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/appendices/unavailable-tools.htm):

> Some geoprocessing tools that are available in other ArcGIS Desktop
>   applications such as ArcMap are not available in ArcGIS Pro.
>   Geoprocessing tools that process data formats that are not supported
>   in ArcGIS Pro have been removed and cannot be used in the application,
>   from Python, or with ModelBuilder.
>
> Certain toolboxes have been entirely removed from ArcGIS Pro, while
>   others may have just one or a few tools that are not available. See
>   the listing of toolboxes and tools below for detailed information
>   about what is not available, if it may be available at a future
>   release, and potential alternatives for those toolboxes and tools.

If there is anything that you use in ArcMap that you find has not been provided in ArcGIS Pro to the same or greater level then I would encourage you to post an [ArcGIS Idea](https://community.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/) asking for that functionality.